# Redefine section headings for my appendix sections to be a full page

Tags: sectioning

I am creating a document (document class is `article`) with several appendix sections.  I change from numeric to alphabetic like this without problem:

```
\setcounter{ldelim}section{rdelim}{ldelim}0{rdelim}

\renewcommand{ldelim}\thesection{rdelim}{ldelim}    
\Alph{ldelim}section{rdelim}{rdelim}
```

What I need to do at that point is to change the section header to be a full page with large bold text that looks something like this (but centered):

> Appendix A
>
> This is the name
>
> of this appendix

then from there do a page break and then continue normal processing on the next page.  I have seen examples with slight differences in font, size, etc., but nothing this drastic.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi and welcome, i bet i am not the only one who is completely puzzled by what you are asking for. Can elaborate on that, best providing a minimal working example so that we can actually understand what you want by seeing simple code?

Comment: package `appendix` might be of interest to you. Or in other words, you do know the `\appendix` command, right? It does what you are doing by hand above.

Comment: I want to specify a section:

\section{This is the name of this appendix}

and have that generate a full page with large bold text at the beginning of the section rather than just "A  This is the name of this appendix"

Comment: So you basicaly want to have a `part` that creates a `section` toc entry? It is important for us to know which document class you are using, and if you are maybe using package `appendix`. Right now, nobody will invest time just to hear »Oh, no, i want it differently, i am using `xyclass`. The solution is much easier for a KOMA class than for standard `article`.  Please provide a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html). <- Link

Comment: I stated in the original question that I was using article.  I am not using appendix class, but would certainly be willing to do so.  Not sure what a minimal code sample would be.  The current code set is dozens of pages long.  A basic example in article would probably be enough for me to figure out the rest - I just need a direction.

Answer (score 2):

With a big part of guesswork and very little imagination i came up with this. Since there weren't really any specs in the question, the following example is kept simple and in no way *fancy*.

[image: warrenAppendixpage]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\appendixsection}[1]{\clearpage\vspace*{.3\textwidth}\begingroup\Huge\bfseries%
\refstepcounter{section}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection}#1}%
\noindent\appendixname~\thesection\par\noindent#1\par\endgroup\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\appendix
\appendixsection{This is the name of this appendix}
\blindtext
\subsection{test}
\appendixsection{This is the name of another appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail because I do not know what I do not know, but that is EXACTLY what I was looking for!  Thank you so much.